# Как выделить столбец в таблице JS?

Tags: javascript

Имеется скрипт js который должен пробежаться по таблице и выделить весь столбец в таблице

```js
let tr_list = document.getElementById('table').getElementsByTagName('tr');

for (let i = 0; i < tr_list.length; i++) {
  tr_list[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[1].className = 'attention';
}
```

```css
.attention {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Наименование</th>
      <th scope="col">Ед.изм</th>
      <th scope="col">Количество</th>
      <th scope="col">Цена</th>
      <th scope="col">Сумма</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td>@fat</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">4</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

Имеется Стиль и таблица. Почему этот скрипт JS не работает. И как сделать так что бы он пробегался по таблице и выделял весь столбец в стиль?

Comment: Если вам мой ответ помог, отметить его галочкой, как ответ. P.S. тут надо писать комментарии

Comment: Михаил, а какой параметр надо изменить что бы выделить определённый столбец?

Comment: обратиться по селектору CSS можно

Comment: А как? Какой параметр?

Comment: по селектору, как в обычном CSS обращаетесь к элементам, так и в JS можно по селектору кого-то выбрать при помощи `querySelector`

Comment: Спасибо, будем разбираться)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так?

```js
const tr_list = document.querySelectorAll('table tr')

tr_list.forEach((item, i) => {
    const td_item = item.querySelector('td');
    if (td_item !== null) {
        td_item.classList.add('active');
    }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Наименование</th>
      <th scope="col">Ед.изм</th>
      <th scope="col">Количество</th>
      <th scope="col">Цена</th>
      <th scope="col">Сумма</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td>@fat</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">4</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: не мне же надо будет потом value значение перебирать и считать цену в сумму